# What is the average membrane potential for a neuron?

Tags: neuroscience

I'm familiar with the resting membrane potential and other relevant values, but I wondered if there was any research done on the average subthreshold potential of a neuronal membrane over time.

Comment: The average subthreshold potential varies greatly with the type of neuron as well as with brain state. In some states, like slow wave sleep in cortex, the membrane potential oscillates between a hyperpolarized (~rest) and depolarized (~threshold) membrane potential. It's far too broad to come up with an "average" value here.